# SQL Loader: Double quotes inside double quotes

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Hi I have problem loading data with double quotes inside double quotes. I always got rejected and save in bad file.

My sql scripts is like this.

```
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL ( 
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    records delimited by newline
    STRING SIZES ARE IN CHARACTERS
      logfile DIR_LOGS:'logs%p.log'
      badfile DIR_LOGS:'bads%p.bad'
      discardfile DIR_LOGS:'discarded%p.dsc'
    fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
    missing field values are NULL
    )
```

My data is like this:

```
Name, Address, Company Name,
"Juan "Julio" Dela Cruz", "Block 5, lot6 Frobes Subd", "REGUS Corp "A"".
"Ferdinand Magellan", "Block 5, lot6, Frobes Subd", "REGUS Corp"
```

I want to retain the double quotes in the name and company.
Juan "Julio" Dela Cruz and REGUS Corp "A". What can you guys recommend?

Comment: Actually I'm not allowed to change the data but will try this..

Comment: Use the double quotes two times(without space) and see if it works. Like this -- `Juan "Julio" Dela Cruz` --> `Juan ""Julio"" Dela Cruz`

Comment: You appear to be using an external table, not the SQL\*Loader tool. In which case, can you use a preprocessor script to escape (double-up) the quotes you want to retain - assuming you can reliably identify them?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do, as far as SQL*Loader is concerned. If values are *optionally enclosed* into double quotes, then you can **NOT** have double quotes within those values.

If you aren't allowed to modify data, you have to find someone who can so that *optionally enclosing* character is changed to something else (i.e. not the double quote). Otherwise you won't be able to successfully load data.